# UITableView inside UITableViewCell height not working as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift3

I have a **UITableView** which have some cells that will be always be there, one cell with a **UICollectionView** in it that will act like tabs, and finally one cell with a **UITableView** in it, whose data will change.

Then when the user selects one of this "tabs", I want to reload the nested table to show the correct data rows (the height of this rows will be dynamic).

I have already achieved that the nested table changes on the collection item selection, but the problem I am facing is that the UITableView inside the cell is not sizing properly.

I have build a sample app just to simplify the views. As you can see in the screenshot, the cell that contains the table is not filling the rest of the screen, so the 10 rows are not visible unless you scroll this table.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

What I want is this table to **fill** the rest of the screen. The user must be able to scroll the main tableview, not the nested one, and still see all of the nested table cells.

I can't do this with multiple sections because I will have a header section that will be always fixed on top, if I had another section, it's header will replace the sticky one on scroll.

I have set the `rowHeight` of the main UITableView to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and an `estimatedRowHeight` too. I have pinned it to top, left, right and bottom of the cell's ContentView.

Can you help me with this, please? If it helps, I could upload the sample project and link it here.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using autolayout then,

Give height constant to nested table view, create outlet for that height constraint.

When you reload that nested table, you will get that table's content size.

Fetch height from that content size and modify height constraint.

Comment: I have tried your solution and when I give the nested table a height constraint, it changes the size to this arbitrary value, but when I reload the table, it does not change anything. To set the value of the height constraint, I do:

    `self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height`

Comment: You need to add this in cellForRow of parent tableview, so when you reload it will recalculate and set to nested table. And also your above line will come after reloading your nested Table.

Comment: Ok, now the nested table fills the rest of the space available, but I can't see all of it's rows unless I scroll the nested tableview. I want the nested table view to overflow the main table (I'm not sure if I am explaining this correctly).

I don't want the user to see that there are 2 tableviews, I don't want the nested table to be scrollable, I want it to act like if it was one single tableview.

Comment: The height of all cells in the nested table is variable or same? If same then you can manually calculate total height and can assign to height constraint and then can call reload data on the nested table to show all your records.

Comment: The height is variable

Comment: after reload data on table view use this
[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
and then use content size property to fetch height.